# listings package und set lstinline style?

Tags: listings, verbatim, code, program

I set 3 styles in my lecture notes for 3 different code style enviroments (`\lstdefinestyle` and `\lstnewenvironment`).
How can I set the `\lstinline` style to one of these? Or is it not possible?

Because the `lstinline` has very small font now and is not uniform with the normal text. (the documentation doesn't really help there? :/)

Here is an example code

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,fleqn,ngerman]{report} %Koma-Script Class article

\RequirePackage{listings}               % Programmierprachen
\let\l\lstinline
\let\t\text
\RequirePackage{lmodern}                % customized font size 
\RequirePackage{color}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.31,0.31,0.31}

% style for appendix with smaller size for the appendix with custom size 9pt
\lstdefinestyle{small_customf95}{
    % belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=none,
    xleftmargin=0.5cm,
    language=[95]Fortran,
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{mygray},
    % identifierstyle=\color{blue},
    % stringstyle=\color{orange},
}
\lstset{mathescape=true,escapeinside={@}{@},style=small_customf95}

\lstnewenvironment{smallf95}{%
    \lstset{%
        mathescape=true,escapeinside={@}{@},style=small_customf95,
    }
}{}

% style for appendix with smaller size for the appendix with custom size 9pt, very small !!! only use
%if the other size is still to big !!!
\lstdefinestyle{smaller_customf95}{
    % belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=none,
    xleftmargin=0.5cm,
    language=[95]Fortran,
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{mygray},
    % identifierstyle=\color{blue},
    % stringstyle=\color{orange},
}
\lstset{mathescape=true,escapeinside={@}{@},style=smaller_customf95}

\lstnewenvironment{smallerf95}{%
    \lstset{%
        mathescape=true,escapeinside={@}{@},style=smaller_customf95,
    }
}{}

%default style for F95 code for the actual lectures, size 8pt
\lstdefinestyle{customf95}{
    % belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=none,
    xleftmargin=0.5cm,
    language=[95]Fortran,
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{mygray},
    % identifierstyle=\color{blue},
    % stringstyle=\color{orange},
}
%\lstset{mathescape=true,escapeinside={@}{@},style=customf95}
\lstnewenvironment{basicf95}{%
    \lstset{%
        mathescape=true,escapeinside={@}{@},style=customf95
    }
}{}

\begin{document}
    test \l{ADVANCE=?}.
\begin{basicf95}
    PROGRAM test
        IF blabla
            ...
        END IF
    END PROGRAM test
\end{basicf95}
\l{ADVANCE=?} - now?
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please always post your `MWE`, i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that will help others to understand the exact problem and also helps to give correct suggestion....

Comment: see the pastebin example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define *one* style and make the suitable adjustments when defining the environments: a change in the overall style will be reflected also in all three environments and in the inline version.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,fleqn,ngerman]{report} %Koma-Script Class article
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{listings}               % Programmierprachen
\usepackage{lmodern}                % customized font size 
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.31,0.31,0.31}

% style for appendix with smaller size for the appendix with custom size 9pt

\lstdefinestyle{customf95}{
    % belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=none,
    xleftmargin=0.5cm,
    language=[95]Fortran,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{mygray},
    % identifierstyle=\color{blue},
    % stringstyle=\color{orange},
    mathescape=true,
    escapeinside={@}{@},
}

\lstnewenvironment{basicf95}
 {%
  \lstset{
    style=customf95,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  }%
 }{}

\lstnewenvironment{smallf95}
 {%
  \lstset{
    style=customf95,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  }%
 }{}
\lstnewenvironment{smallerf95}
 {%
  \lstset{
    style=customf95,
    basicstyle=\fontsize{9pt}{11pt}\ttfamily,
  }%
 }{}
\newcommand{\inlinef}[1][]{%
  \lstinline[style=customf95,basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1]%
}


\begin{document}

test \inlinef{ADVANCE=?}.

\begin{basicf95}
    PROGRAM test
        IF blabla
            ...
        END IF
    END PROGRAM test
\end{basicf95}

\inlinef{ADVANCE=?} - now?

\begin{smallerf95}
    PROGRAM test
        IF blabla
            ...
        END IF
    END PROGRAM test
\end{smallerf95}

\inlinef{ADVANCE=?} - now?

\begin{smallf95}
    PROGRAM test
        IF blabla
            ...
        END IF
    END PROGRAM test
\end{smallf95}

\inlinef{ADVANCE=?} - now?

\end{document}
```

Avoid redefine `\l` and `\t`: when your bibliography will contain the name of some Polish author you'd regret having redefined `\l`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The manual says, that `\lstinline` takes an optional argument, where you can set the style:

```
test \lstinline[style=customf95]{ADVANCE=?}.
```

[image]

Also, if you need short inline code, you can define

```
\lstMakeShortInline[style=customf95]|
```

Which can be used like [shortvrb](https://ctan.org/pkg/shortvrb)

```
test |ADVANCE=?|.
```